# What is the residue of a even function?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Suppose that the function $f(z)$ has an isolated singularity  at point $a\in \Bbb C$. Now suppose that $f(z)$ is even  in $(z-a)$, i.e.
$$
f(z-a) = f(-(z-a))
$$
**Claim**: the residue of $f(z)$ at $a$ is zero.

How i can do this ?? Any help is highly appreciated. Please help and give  a  descriptive  one.

Comment: Make a circular contour about $a$ and split it into four pieces. Pair them up in the right way and they should cancel.

Comment: For example, consider a polynomial $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2$, and I tell you that $P(z)=P(-z)$ for every $z\in\Bbb{C}$. Can you prove $a_1=0$? Well, for your question write down the Laurent expansion about $a$, and apply a similar reasoning to deduce the residue is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, take $a=0.$ Then $f$ is analytic in $U=\{0<|z|<r\}$ for some $r>0,$ and we have $f(-z)=f(z)$ there. Let $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz_n$ be the Laurent expansion of $f$ in $U.$ Then

$$f(-z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_n(-1)^nz^n = f(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz_n,\,\, z\in U.$$

By the uniqueness of the Laurent expansion, $a_n=a_n(-1)^n$ for all $n.$ In particular, $a_{-1}= a_{-1}(-1)^{-1} = -a_{-1}.$ Therefore $a_{-1}=0,$ which is the desired result.

Comment: Hey, does being even in a point implies being even in a neighborhood?

Comment: @e.ad  Certainly not. For example let $f(z) = (z+1)^2(z-1).$ Then $f(-1) = 0= f(1),$ but $f$ is not even.

Comment: then why in the second line of your solution you stated that we have f(z) = f(-z) in a neighborhood of z?
My apology if I didn't understand you correctly

Comment: @e.ad I don't  why you're saying this. It's clear that $z$ is not some fixed point but rather is a variable taking values in $U.$

Comment: You're right I related the given as for fixed point $z-a$.. :/ So however $f$ is even for every $z$ right? because we can plug $w=z+a$ and get $f(w) = f(-w)$
Thank you

Comment: Usually "even" does not refer to a single point. It refers to all variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$2\pi i Res_a{f} = \int_{\partial B(a,r)}f(z) \\
=  \int_{\partial B(0,r)}f(z-a) \\
= \int_{\partial B(0,r)}f(-(z-a)) \\
= -\int_{\partial B(a,r)}f(z) \\
= -2\pi i Res_a{f}
$$

Comment: Your first line should be $$\text{Res}_a{f} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,r)}f(z)$$